# Wget all files from httpdocs or example.com/*

Tags: server, backup, wget

In my job I often have to move websites from one server to another.

Till now I zipped all the files from origin's server httpdocs to a backup.zip and downloaded it on new server with `wget old_domain.com/backup.zip`, after the downloaded I extracted the zip file.

Is there a way, to wget all files from old_domain.com?

Something like `wget example.com/*` did not work.

I'm always have the root access to the origin's server.

It would be really great, when I can't avoid the .zip file, because the backups are about 50GB and packing & extracting take more than a hour.

Comment: `wget` is useful for mirroring someone else’s website but it cannot transfer any server-side scripts and files that no page links to. If you are the maintainer of the origin server, you should prefer FTP, SCP or similar methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` over FTP, like this:

```
wget -m \
    --user=$FTPUSERNAME --password=$FTPPASSWORD \
    -o $LOGFILE -P $LOCALDIR ftp://example.com/sourcedir
```

with `-m`: use mirroring and `-P`: target directory.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just do not understand what is mirroring...
Do I see right: 
'wget -m \ --user=$FTPUSERNAME --password=$FTPPASSWORD \ -o $LOGFILE -P /var/www/vhosts/my_domain/httpdocs ftp://example.com/httpdocs'

is one line?

Which one will be faster: zip > wget file.zip > unzip oder wget ftp://...?

Comment: No, on one line, you would leave out the `\`. As for speed, zipping on the server (i.e. before downloading) may be faster if network speed is a problem. But I don't like the extra step. BTW for this kind of job I normally use Filezilla.

Comment: So one line would be 'wget -m --user=$FTPUSERNAME --password=$FTPPASSWORD -o $LOGFILE -P /var/www/vhosts/my_domain/httpdocs example.com/httpdocs' ?

Downloading via wget it's about 11Mbit, but I don't know which speed will be via ftp. Filezilla ist not an option, cuz I use mobile internet

Comment: I tried that out and found out, that zip > wget > unzip is faster than wget from ftp. Thank you